# std::stringstream as parameter

Tags: c++, logging, parameters, stringstream

I'm somewhat new to the C++ language. I'm writing a utility class for logging to file. It works beautifully except that now I would like to enhance it by making it more convenient to use (e.g. pass stringstreams to a log function).

This is what I've been trying and it hasn't worked.

definition:

`void LogStream( std::stringstream i_Log ){
m_FileHandle << i_Log << std::endl; 
}`

call:

`m_LogObject->LogStream( "MKLBSearchEngine::Search( " << x << ", " << i_Filter << " ) - No Results Found" );`

Comment: What doesn't work? Errors, wrong behavior?

Answer (score 11):

There are several problems with your solution.  The first is that you're
passing `stringstream` by value, and it doesn't support copy.  You need
by reference.  The second is that at the call site, the return value of
the `operator<<` overloads is `ostream&`, not `stringstream`, and since
`stringstream` isn't a base class of `ostream&` (it's the other way
round), you can't initialize the `stringstream` (or the `stringstream&`)
with it.  And finally, there's no `operator<<` which takes a
`stringstream` as the right hand parameter, so the statement in the
`LogStream` function can't work.  Finally, this is going to be somewhat
awkward for the user anyway.  A log of `operator<<` are non-members,
with an `ostream&` non-const reference as first argument, so you can't
call them with a temporary as the left argument.  (In your example call,
of course, you forgot to create the `std::ostringstream` anyway; it
won't compiler because there is no overload of `<<` which takes a `char
const[]` or a `char const*` as its left hand operand.)

There are work-arounds for almost all of these problems.  Something
like:

```
void LogStream( std::ostream& text )
{
    std::ostringstream& s = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(text);
    m_FileHandle << s.str() << std::endl;
}
```

handles all of the problems except the last; the last has to be handled
by the client, something like:

```
m_LogObject->LogStream( std::ostringstream().flush() << "..." << x );
```

(The call to `std::ostream::flush()` returns a non-const reference to
the stream, which can be used to initialize further `std::ostream&`.
And while you can't initialize a non-const reference with a temporary,
you can call a non-const member function on it.)

The awkwardness of this for the client code makes me generally prefer a
more complex solution.  I define a special `LogStreamer` class,
something like:

```
class LogStreamer
{
    boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream > m_collector;
    std::ostream* m_dest;

public:
    LogStreamer( std::ostream& dest )
        , m_collector( new std::ostringstream )
        , m_dest( &dest )
    {
    }
    ~LogStreamer()
    {
        if ( m_collector.unique() ) {
            *m_dest << m_collector->str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    template <typename T>
    LogStreamer& operator<<( T const& value )
    {
        *m_collector << value;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and

```
LogStreamer LogStream() { return LogStreamer( m_FileHandle ); }
```

The client code can then write:

```
m_LogObject->LogStream() << "..." << x;
```

In my own code: the log object is always a singleton, the call is
through a macro, which passes `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to the `LogStream()`
function, and the final target ostream is a special streambuf with a
special function, called by `LogStream()`, which takes a filename and a
line number, outputs them, along with the time stamp, at the start of
the next line output, and indents all other lines.  A filtering
streambuf with something like:

```
class LogFilter : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* m_finalDest;
    std::string m_currentHeader;
    bool m_isAtStartOfLine;
protected:
    virtual int overflow( int ch )
    {
        if ( m_isAtStartOfLine ) {
            m_finalDest->sputn( m_currentHeader.data(), m_currentHeader.size() );
            m_currentHeader = "    ";
        }
        m_isAtStartOfLine = (ch == '\n');
        return m_finalDest->sputc( ch );
    }
    virtual int sync()
    {
        return m_finalDest->sync();
    }

public:
    LogFilter( std::streambuf* dest )
        : m_finalDest( dest )
        , m_currentHeader( "" )
        , m_isAtStartOfLine( true )
    {
    }
    void startEntry( char const* filename, int lineNumber )
    {
        std::ostringstream header;
        header << now() << ": " << filename << " (" << lineNumber << "): ";
        m_currentHeader = header.str();
    }
};
```

(The function `now()`, of course, returns a `std::string` with the
timestamp.  Or a `struct tm`, and you've written a `<<` for `tm`.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your design. You don't want to accept a stream as a parameter, either accept a string, or make your class behave as a stream (or both).

If you make your object behave as a stream, then you do the following:

```
m_LogObject << "what to log" << etc;
```

To do that, simply override the `<<` operator.

Comment: Why is this more relevant than the two answers you criticized for being irrelevant?  What's wrong with using a stream as a parameter?

Comment: Because it can't be used the way you want. It won't work. What you could do is pass by constant reference and then you would have to prepend the parameter by `stringstream()`, which isn't exactly convenient.

Comment: Maybe I am misreading this but it seems the error is that OPs call to LogStream is all screwed up.  Is that a string he is a passing?  Some misunderstanding of how to create a stringstream?  In any case, if he was shown how to properly create the stringstream and pass it that would answer his question.

Comment: @Duck Yes, what he wants is to make is class behave as a stream not take it as a parameter.

Comment: Although I agree with you about the other answers, after thoroughly inspecting his incorrect use of his function, your answer isn't that relevant either, as it's a typical "no matter what the solution to your problem is, here is a completely different design approach, to just circumvent your problem"-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your call should look like

```
m_LogObject->LogStream( stringstream() << "MKLBSearchEngine::Search( " << x
 << ", " << i_Filter << " ) - No Results Found" );
```

since you need to create your stringstream object that you will be passing to the function.

This call implies that you already have a desired output stream so i'd also recommend you changing your class design to use `operator<<` for logging unless it is already overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your function call won't work, as `"MKLBSearchEngine::Search( "` is of type const char* and that has no overload for the `<<` operator. It won't work with `std::string("MKLBSearchEngine::Search( ")` either, as also `std::string` doesn't have such an operator. What you can do is call it with `std::stringstream("MKLBSearchEngine::Search( ")`, which converts the first argument to a stream, such that the following operators work on this stream. But as others pointed out, you will have to make the function argument a const reference, as streams are not copyable (even then it would be quite inefficient). Also just writing a `std::stringstream` into the file won't do what you want (if it works anyway), instead you have to take its contents (the underlying `std::string`). So all in all your code should look like:

```
void LogStream( const std::stringstream &i_Log ){ m_FileHandle << i_Log.str() << std::endl; }
...
m_LogObject->LogStream( std::stringstream("MKLBSearchEngine::Search( ") << x << ", " << i_Filter << " ) - No Results Found" );
```

But you could also just use a `LogString(const std::string &)` and let the user of this function call `stream.str()` himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass stream objects by value (since they are not copyable), so you need to pass by (and store) references:

```
void LogStream(std::stringstream& i_Log){
    m_FileHandle << i_Log << std::endl;
}
```

This probably won't do what you're expecting though (it will probably print an address of i_Log, for rather obscure reasons).

If your intention is to take stuff OUT of the stringstream, this might do what you want:

```
i_Log.get( *m_FileHandle.rdbuf() );
```

Comment: That's kind of irrelevant :-D Read the question properly.

Comment: @Christian It is, and it won't work since you need to pass by constant reference for it to work. And still, it doesn't solve the bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `std::stringstream` instance by value. You want to avoid copying and pass it by reference (or pointer). For example:

```
void LogStream ( std::stringstream & i_Log ){ m_FileHandle << i_Log << std::endl; }
```

Read more about C++ [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29).

Comment: That's kind of irrelevant :-D Read the question properly.